# crop viewport of used display screenspace

Tags: xrandr

I have hdmi display that has 1920x1080.

I would love to use only part of it, e.g. 1600x1080 or 800x800.

Following does not work, and combinations of it that I tried:

```
$ xrandr --output HDMI-1 --primary --fb 1920x1080 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --panning 800x800 --rotate normal

X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  29 (RRSetPanning)
  Serial number of failed request:  41
  Current serial number in output stream:  41
```

Or other viewpoerts positions like:

```
x=242 y=30 windowsize 1436x1051
```

So I don't have to adjust all windows with xdotool, but just have this as my screen size, so environment, taskbar/systemtray, maximized windows etc simply everything fits and is visible in given rectangle.